How would this desert town dispose of waste?
I'm working on a no-magic fantasy world with your standard medieval-esque technology. My world has a town on the shore of a salt lake in the middle of a desert. The town is built upon the very precious salt it produces and sells, with 5,000-7,000 people now living in the town. That many people in one place creates quite a bit of waste, a lot of it organic.
I've struggled to find a reasonable way for the town to dispose of waste. Being in an arid environment luckily means that the waste won't stink as much or be quite as much of a breeding ground for disease, but it also means that the waste will last a while. Throwing it in the streets would be a public health hazard, but throwing it in a dump a mile away would be a pretty big hassle. Throwing it in the salt lake is a no-no because its water is evaporated to make salt, the town's primary export, and if the salt is contaminated, the town's salt trade would plummet, and then there would be no town. Everything I've seen online about how waste disposal worked in the premodern age assumes we're working with a So how could this town dispose of its waste?

Given that real world settlements have dealt with the problem of waste for the totality of human existence this seems like something that could be solved with basic research.

What is wrong with the thousands of years old occupation of nightman? It is an honorable station in life. (And there is no way that a town of 5,000 inhabitants lives on the proceeds of salt extraction. Salt extraction is a very low paid occupation. At the place of production, salt is only slightly more valuable than dirt. At the place of consumption, the cost of salt is almost 100% the cost of transportation plus taxes.)

To follow on Sphennings's comment: what is the worldbuilding problem you're trying to solve here? A basic web search reveals the surface answers. What's the underlying issue you've got, if the surface answers aren't good enough?

-1 for failing to research the issue or, if the research was indeed adequate, for not explaining why what humanity actually did for thousands and thousands of years isn't good enough.

For a population that size you're going to need something other than salt unless there's nowhere else in the entire world including the ocean to get salt.. it's a remarkably labour light product, time intensive and requiring a lot of space if you're using evaporation pools of course .. but it really doesn't need that many people per acre dedicated to it's production to manage the process once the pools are established even for pretty large quantities.

Recycle what they can and bury the rest. Food waste becomes animal feed. Manure and urine can be used as fertilizer. Dried manure can be fuel for fires (there is little wood in a desert).
What cannot be used is buried. Dig a deep hole and fill it. Once full, dig another.
